# remove last characters string batch

Tags: batch-file

hello I need to generate list of images in a txt file, but I have to remove the last character and delete duplicates

example

```
SDFDFDF_1.jpg
SDFDFDF_2.jpg
THGGHFG_1.jpg
THGGHFG_2.jpg
```

and would have to stay that way in txt list

```
SDFDFDF
THGGHFG
```

my code removes only .jpg

```
@echo off
if exist "sku.txt" del "sku.txt"
for /f "delims=" %%f in ('dir *.jpg /b') do echo %%~nf >> sku.txt
```

Comment: `%string:~0,-5%`. Try it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If extensions are enabled, this should work:

```
@echo off
if exist "sku.txt" del "sku.txt"
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set list=
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%f in (`dir /b *.jpg`) do (
  set xx=%%~nf
  set candidate=!xx:~0,-2!
  set n=0
  for %%i in (!list!) do (
    if "!candidate!"=="%%i" (
      set n=1
    )
  )
  if !n! EQU 0 (
    set list=!list! !candidate!
    echo !candidate! >> sku.txt
  )
)

endlocal
```

Answer (score 67):

## Substrings

Batch supports syntax for taking a substring out of a string. The general syntax for this is

```
%string:~start,end%
```

**Basic usage:**

```
set test=test
echo %test:~2,3%
::st
```

---

How does this apply to your question? When a negative number is used as the end index, the substring stops that many characters before the end of the string. This behavior makes it easy to drop characters from the end of a string.

```
set test=test
echo %test:~0,-1%
::tes
```

Comment: Works great as long as you do not have a colon in the string.

Comment: Even works with a colon.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "prev="
(
 FOR /f "tokens=1delims=_" %%a IN (
    'dir /b /o:n /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.jpg" '
  ) DO (
  CALL :unique %%a
 )
)>u:\newfile.txt

GOTO :EOF

:unique
IF /i "%prev%"=="%1" GOTO :EOF
SET "prev=%1"
ECHO(%1
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

Produces u:\newfile.txt

The procedure performs a directory list of the source directory, in basic format (filenames only) without directories and in order of name, assignig each name to `%%a` but the `delims`  option assigns only that part before the delimiter (`_`)

The `unique` subroutine compares its parameter (the partial-filename) to the previous name found (case-insensitive) and if they're different, sets `prev` to the newly-found name and `echo`es it.

Answer (score 0):

Your specification is very imprecise. You state you need to remove the last character of the name, yet you remove the extension, plus the two preceding characters (underscore and digit).

What if you have a file named ABC_12.jpg?

What if you have ABC.jpg?

I'll assume you want to only deal with files that look like *_n.jpg, where n is a digit.

You can use my [JREN.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6081) to get a list of all files that match the template, and strip off the last two characters plus extension. You can pipe that to my [JSORT.BAT utility](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=5595) to sort and remove duplicates. Both utilities are hybrid JScript/batch scripts that run natively on any Windows machine from XP onward.

```
jren ".{6}$" "" /list /rfm "_\d\.jpg$"|jsort /u /i >sku.txt
```