# cmd - Remove last \ from the searched folder

Tags: cmd

I need folder's full path given it has .txt file

Currently I am using the following command

```
D:\Testfolder\_dn>for /r %i in (*.txt) do @echo %~dpi
```

And getting the following output

```
D:\Testfolder\_dn\2nd\
D:\Testfolder\_dn\3rd\
D:\Testfolder\_dn\4th\
D:\Testfolder\_dn\5th\
D:\Testfolder\_dn\first\
```

But I want the output like following

```
D:\Testfolder\_dn\2nd
D:\Testfolder\_dn\3rd
D:\Testfolder\_dn\4th
D:\Testfolder\_dn\5th
D:\Testfolder\_dn\first
```

I tried [remove last characters string batch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29504225/1772898)

```
for /r %i in (*.txt) do @echo %~dpi:~0,-1%
```

But it is not working.

How can I remove the last \ from the search result?

Comment: The [sub-string expansion syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) does not work for `for` variable references, you need to use normal environment variables instead; regard to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion) when editing variable values within a block of code or a loop!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [sub-string expansion syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) works on normal environment variables only, but not on [`for`](http://ss64.com/nt/for.html) variable references. To apply that syntax you need to assign the value to a variable first:

```cmd
for /R %i in ("*.txt") do @(set "VAR=%~dpi" & echo/!VAR:~^,-1!)
```

But since you are editing a variable value within a block of code (loop), you need to enable and to apply [delayed variable expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). This can be established by opening the command line instance by `cmd /V:ON` or `cmd /V`. However, this can still cause trouble when a path contains `!`-symbols.

---

An alternative and better solution is to avoid string manipulation and delayed variable expansion by appending `.` to the paths (meaning the current directory) and using another `for` loop to resolve the paths by the [`~f` modifier](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html) of the variable reference, like this:

```cmd
for /R %i in ("*.txt") do @for %j in ("%~dpi.") do @echo/%~fj
```

The `""` avoid problems with paths containing <kbd>SPACEs</kbd> or other token separators (`,`, `;`, `=`,...).

Comment: I don't know why but the code that worked for me is for /R %i in ("*.txt") do [at the rate]for %j in ("%~dpi.") do [at the rate]echo %~fj

Comment: It works because a path like `D:\Testfolder\_dn\first\.` (note the appended dot) is the same as `D:\Testfolder\_dn\first`, and `~f` resolves such things...

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to enable delayed expansion so that the `P` variable gets reevaluated in the loop.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

for /r %%i in (*.txt) do (
    SET "P=%%~dpi"
    echo !P:~0,-1!
)
```

Comment: This is batch file code/syntax, not for `cmd` directly, so you need to double the `%`-signs! However, the question is *not* tagged [tag:batch-file]...