# Windows Batch - delete last characters from variable

Tags: windows, batch-file, string-function

I need to delete the last 3 characters from a variable in Windows batch

```
set string=abcdefghij
```

I need the following output:

```
abcdefg
```

I can delete the first 3 characters from the variable using this:

```
set newstring=%string:~3,100%
echo %newstring%
```

Output:

```
defghij
```

But how can I delete the last 3 characters from the string - and store the result into a variable?

I can show the string without the last 3 characters by using sed (from GnuWin32) but I also need to store the result into another variable. I need a better solution than storing the result in a file and then reading the file into a variable (set /p newstring=<file.txt)

Later note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503925/remove-last-characters-string-batch) is very different, it needs removing last characters from a multi-line text, while I need removing last characters from a variable.

Comment: open up a command prompt and type: `set /?| more /e +92 | findstr /li path` for the syntax of using substring modification to trim the end of a string

Comment: Duplicate -  [remove last characters string batch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29503925/remove-last-characters-string-batch)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just use negative index

```
set longtext=1234567890
:: Remove last 3 characters
echo %longtext:~0,-3%
:: show last three characters
echo %longtext:~-3%
```

Output:

```
1234567
890
```

Comment: Thanks. I needed this today. Tested - works fine. Windows 11.